# Negative float Issue - Python (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am having trouble with a line of my code where I can do positive numbers but I can't add a `-` sign in front of the numbers to make it a negative number.

Here is the code:

```
as_meter = dict(mm=0.001, cm=0.01, inch=0.0254,ft=0.3048, yd=0.9144, m=1.0,km=1000.0, mi=1609.344,)
def update_length(self, *args):
    try:
        v = float(self.Text_Length_Left.get())
    except ValueError:
        self.Text_Length_Left.set('')
        self.Text_Length_Right.set('')
        return
```

Here is the Left entry box code where you enter the float:

```
self.Text_Length_Left = StringVar()
self.Entry_Length_Left = ttk.Entry(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.Text_Length_Left,width = 13)
self.Text_Length_Left.trace('w', self.update_length)
self.Entry_Length_Left.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit

Code to run it:

```
class Conversion:

as_meter = dict(mm=0.001, cm=0.01, inch=0.0254,ft=0.3048, yd=0.9144, m=1.0,km=1000.0, mi=1609.344,)
def update_length(self, *args):
    try:
        v = float(self.Text_Length_Left.get())
    except ValueError:
        self.Text_Length_Left.set('')
        self.Text_Length_Right.set('')
        return
    m = v * self.as_meter [self.measurements.get()]
    r = m/self.as_meter[self.measurements1.get()]
    self.Text_Length_Right.set("{:.5g}".format(r))

class GUI(Conversion):
def __init__(self,root):
    self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
    self.notebook.pack()

    self.length_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
    self.weight_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
    self.temperature_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
    self.help_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)

    self.notebook.add(self.length_frame, text = 'Length')

    #Combobox
    self.measurements = StringVar()
    self.Combobox_Length_Left = ttk.Combobox(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.measurements, values = ('mm', 'cm', 'inch', 'ft', 'yd', 'm', 'km', 'mi'), width = 10,state=['readonly'])
    self.Combobox_Length_Left.current(5)
    self.measurements.trace('w', self.update_length)
    self.Combobox_Length_Left.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

    self.measurements1 = StringVar()
    self.Combobox_Length_Right = ttk.Combobox(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.measurements1, value = ('mm', 'cm', 'inch', 'ft', 'yd', 'm', 'km', 'mi'), width = 10,state = ['readonly'])
    self.Combobox_Length_Right.current(5)
    self.measurements1.trace('w', self.update_length)
    self.Combobox_Length_Right.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

    #Labels
    self.Conversion = ttk.Label(self.length_frame, text = 'Convertion:').grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = W)
    self.Label_Blank = ttk.Label(self.length_frame, text = '').grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
    self.Label_To2 = ttk.Label(self.length_frame, text = 'to').grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
    self.Label_To = ttk.Label(self.length_frame, text = 'to').grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

    #Entry Boxes
    self.Text_Length_Left = StringVar()
    self.Entry_Length_Left = ttk.Entry(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.Text_Length_Left,width = 13)
    self.Text_Length_Left.trace('w', self.update_length)
    self.Entry_Length_Left.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.Text_Length_Right = StringVar()
    self.Entry_Length_Right = ttk.Entry(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.Text_Length_Right,width = 13, state='readonly')
    self.Entry_Length_Right.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
enter code here
```

Comment: can you elaborate on " I can't add a - sign in front of the numbers" is there an error? what happens when you do? or the entry box wont allow the "-" character when you try to type it in? You do realize we cannot run the code you have provided? please post a verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of casting directly the entered text to float, you can check if there is a minus character at the beginning of the string:

```
def update_length(self, *args):

    entered_value = self.Text_Length_Left.get()

    if entered_value.startswith('-'):
        sign = -1
        entered_value = entered_value.replace('-', '', 1)
    else:
        sign = 1

    try:
        v = float(entered_value)
    except ValueError:
        self.Text_Length_Right.set('Invalid input')
        return
    m = v * sign * self.as_meter [self.measurements.get()]
    r = m/self.as_meter[self.measurements1.get()]
    self.Text_Length_Right.set("{:.5g}".format(r))
```

You were not able to input anything other that numbers because of the `self.Text_Length_Left.set('')` which cleared the input box when you did so.

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I posed the whole code and I tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ReganKelly can you elaborate a bit ? What did you modify ? What isn't working ?

Comment: I didn't modify any of it because I know by looking at it should work because it does look fine. Like when I try put the negative sign in it doesn't enter it because of the `ValueError`.

Comment: @ReganKelly can you add a `print(entered_value)` before the try/except block, and see what comes out of it ?

Comment: Yeah I tried it when I added the `-` sign it printed it but it wasn't showing in the Entry box

Comment: Do you want pictures?

Comment: Yeah it might help me understand what the problem is.

Comment: Here you go I pressed the `-` but it didn't show up shown in the picture https://gyazo.com/8292fe47e384e2eafdb9d77acfa2e8cc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113488/discussion-between-3kt-and-regan-kelly).